# How to stop selenium script for 20 minutes

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java

I have an automated blazemeter (load testing software) that takes 20 to 30 minutes to do its work. While my blazemeter script is running I want to stop my Selenium script and after that I want to collect the reports.

How to do this?

Which type of wait should  I use for this?

Comment: Cant you use a timer ?

Comment: OP: What are your programming skills?

Comment: Please clarify: You want to stop your Selenium script from running when the BlazeMeter test is running? Is your Selenium script running as part of a CI/Build process? Can you schedule your BlazeMeter scripts to run off hours instead of during the your functional test execution window?

Answer (score 3):

You have someways of doing it:

1 - Running your blazemeter scripts as part of your selenium suite

Discover how to call a shell command in your programming language and run your blazemeter scripts as a selenium test- execution will wait until the command ends, and your can get the result.

2 - Set a system variable

You could set your blazemeter scripts to set a global system variable to False at the beginning of its execution and to True at its end. Your selenium tests should just run when the variable is True.

Answer (score 1):

Your Selenium code can use wait only for something which is on the screen/webpage. So does your webpage reflects status of blazemeter: keep waiting vs ok to continue?

If not, you can use your underlying code to check for some condition which blazemeter changes when it is OK to continue (query if could continue, wait some more if not).